# AnjularJS: Iterating through list of objects

Tags: angularjs

I have a language dropdown in my angularjs application. I have a rootScope variable called languages that is list of language objects populated from database. The user selected language is in session variable.  Following is the code snippet.

```
<c:set var="selLanguage" value="${sessionScope['language']}"></c:set>

<span ng-repeat="language in languages">
<c:out value="{{language.languageCode}}"/>
<c:out value="${selLanguage}"/>
<c:if test="{{language.languageCode == selLanguage}}">
    test
</c:if>
</span>
```

The issue i am facing is ... The two c:outs are printed properly (Say EN EN). But I am unable to print 'test'. I wrote many c:if test expressions but none of them worked. What i am trying to print 'test' if the language in session is equal to one of the language in the array. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: JSTL tags are evaluated at server-side, expect JSP EL expressions (`${ ... }`), that use Java objects stored in a servlet scope. AngularJS expressions are evaluated at client-side, expect JavaScript + filters, and use JS variables of the AngularJS $scope. Putting an AngularJS expression in a c:if attribute makes no sense at all.

Comment: Are you sure you want `<c:if>` instead of, say, `<span ng-if>`?  (it looks like you're confusing java and angular here.)

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Is there a way to compare session variable with angularjs scope variable? I tried ng-if also but no luck.